Init FPDF library, destroy fpdf library, Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;=>
I am experiencing an issue with loading PDFs from a network. Small PDFs load properly, but when I try to view a large network PDF, it goes into a loading state and crashes the app.
I receive the following error:

Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
Did not find frame.
destroy fpdf library
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long
java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
W/System.err(29152):  at
com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.renderPageBitmap(PdfiumCore.java:312)
W/System.err(29152):  at
com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PdfFile.renderPageBitmap(PdfFile.java:295)
W/System.err(29152):  at
com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.RenderingHandler.proceed(RenderingHandler.java:109)
W/System.err(29152):  at
com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.RenderingHandler.handleMessage(RenderingHandler.java:66)
W/System.err(29152):  at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
W/System.err(29152):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
W/System.err(29152):  at
android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

I have used flutter_cached_pdfview package.

I have tried to find a solution with an alternative package, Syncfusion, but it also has issues. When I run a large file, it first loads the PDF, but then goes into a loading state and crashes the app.
